# removeAttr from multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

is it possible to use removeAttr from multiple classes and Ids ? i could not find anything for that.

smth like this dont work        `$('.one.two.six.eleven#box').removeAttr("style");`  nor this

```
$(".one.two.three#smth.seven").css("transition", "3s");
```

i cant manage to use removeAttr on multiple classes and id's that are not children of each other :).

i cant also manage to add css() to many free classes that are in window and every has its own parameters but there is some bind to deal with all of them.

in fiddle i have some basic that works but it is for me too long too many lines. seems awfull.

thank you all for answers.

i placed JSfiddle to show mess i made but want to do 'DRY' and 'LIM'.

[fiddle to fork on...](https://jsfiddle.net/elchinsolo/0c9njgLk/)

new edit for explanation

```
    function some_func() {
    $(".some").removeAttr("style");
    $(".thing").css("transition", "3s");
    $(".right").removeAttr("style");
    $(".right").css("transition", "3s");
    $(".left").removeAttr("style");
    $(".left").css("transition", "3s");
    $(".hello").removeAttr("style");
    $(".top").css("transition", "3s");
    $("#car").removeAttr("style");
}
```

how to make it in 2 lines

Answer (score 1):

`$(".one.two.three#smth.seven")` means you are selecting all objects that are of class one, two, three etc.  (I don't even think three#smth will work).

for instance: `<div class="one two three">` will be selected by `$(".one.two.three")`

If you want a union of objects from several selectors, you can comma-separate them:

`$(".one, .two, .three, #smth, .seven")`

This should return you all objects that are either .one or .two or .three or #smth or .seven

i.e. `<div class="one"></div><div class="two"></div><div class="three"></div>` will all be selected.

Comment: hi Morksinaanab thanks for suggestion but not works.  lets say i have <div>'s with classes and divs with ID's and they are all separated some are in another div some are p class some are img classes. also it is not possible to merge them under one .css({}) line

Comment: can you show an example of your code and html to see what's going on? (nevermind, i see the fiddle)

Comment: `$("#buttonella").click(function() {
            $("#box,.right,.right1").css({"display":"block"});
            $("#box").css({
              "background": "red",
              "width": "300px",
              "font-size": "20px",
            });
            $(".right, .right1").css({
              "background": "green",
              "width": "200px",
              "font-size": "30px",
            });
          });`

Comment: `$("#buttonella2").click(function() {
            $('#box, .right').removeAttr("style");
            $('.freebox').removeClass();
            $(".left").css("background", "pink");
          });`

Comment: it is possible though, the multiple selector combines all results. Perhaps you can read through all the options you have as a selector in the jquery documentation: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/. Also I'm not quite clear what the jfiddle is supposed to show

Comment: To make your example more dry: `function some_func() {
    $(".some, .right, .left, .hello, #car").removeAttr("style");
    $(".thing, .right, .left, .top").css("transition", "3s");
}`

Comment: these dont work , i guess it is not possible in jquery to add multiple unbinded selectors and do whole bunch of work. maybe new updates will change it. anyway thanks for efforts.

Comment: not sure what you are testing then, because when i try with your fiddle, the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){
 $('.one,.three,.five').removeAttr('class');
  $('#two,#four').removeAttr('id');
});
```

```css
li{
  color: green;
}
.one{
  color:red;
}
#two{
  color:blue;
}
.three{
  color:purple;
}
#four{
  color:yellow;
}
.five{
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click me</button>
<ul>
  <li class="one">1</li>
  <li id="two">2</li>
  <li class="three">3</li>
  <li id="four">4</li>
  <li class="five">5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for this mmativ, it is pretty well but not for my situation, here are too many manipulations and all in <li>  denpendencies and removing id attribut and class names can ruin my project.

Answer (score 0):

If you can add one common class for all these elements, then you can use that class to remove attribute.

For example -

Html

```
<div class="position right"></div>
<div class="position left"></div>
<div class="position hello"></div>
<div id="car" class="position"></div>
```

Solution

```
$('.position').removeAttr('style')
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#buttonella").click(function() {
    $('.right').addClass('right-toggle');
    $('.right1').addClass('right1-toggle');
    $('#box').addClass('box-toggle');
  });
  $("#buttonella2").click(function() {
    $('#box').removeClass("box-toggle");
    $('.freebox').removeClass();
    $(".left").css("background", "pink");
    $('.right').removeClass('right-toggle');
  });
})
```

```css
:root {
  padding: 20px;
}

[class] {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#buttonella {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 30px;
  float: left;
}

#buttonella2 {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 30px;
  float: right;
}

.box-toggle {
   background: red;
   width: 300px;
   margin: 0px;
   font-size: 20px;
   display: block;
}

.right-toggle, .right1-toggle {
   background: green;
   width: 200px;
   font-size: 30px;
   display: block;
}

.freebox {
  background: red;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttonella">click</div>
<div id="buttonella2">unclick</div>
<div id="box">boxboxboxbxo bxoxboxbox

  <div class="right">right rith ehiteh hereee

  </div>
  <div class="left">left left left here

  </div>
  <div class="right1">right1 class is here
  </div>
</div>
<div class="freebox">freebox class is here

</div>
```